# D3 Mouse Events -- Click & DragEnd

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events

In D3, if you defined a drag function like this:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", function () {alert("drag")})
        .on("dragend", function () {alert("dragEnd")});
```

You really cannot do the following:

```
d3.select("#text1")
.on("click", function(d,i) {alert("clicked")})
.call(drag);
```

Reason is that the click will get fired after that the "dragend" will fire . In my opinion there should be a separate event for clicking because I see a huge difference between dragend and click.

To differentiate between clicking and end of a dragging event in an SVG element, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[The documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-on) has some explicit examples for this:

> When registering your own click listener on draggable elements, you can check whether the click event was suppressed as follows:

```
selection.on("click", function() {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
  console.log("clicked!");
});
```

This, along with the `stopPropagation()` example immediately afterwards, allows you to control which events are fired and handled.

To be clear, differentiating between a drag end and click event is entirely down to you. The easiest way to do this is probably to set a flag when dragging takes place and use that flag to determine whether a `dragend` or `click` event should be handled.

Comment: but this solution doesn't work on Chrome. I mean dragend always fires before click

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.9.0 there is [`.clickDistance()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_clickDistance) with which you can control after which distance moved (from where you started dragging) you won't get a `click` event.

Note that you might get any `click` event at all if you remove the element from the DOM before release of the button (e.g. by using [`.raise()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_raise) in the `drag` handler).

Comment: Does this work in the opposite direction? Where below the click distance, you don't get a drag event?

Comment: @BallpointBen I guess not but if you have a specific use case then post it as a feature request at https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/issues (best with a demo created using http://blockbuilder.org/ or https://observablehq.com/).