# D3 Differentiate between click and drag for an element which has a drag behavior

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, d3.js

I am unable to successfully distinguish between the `click` event and the `drag` event on an element that is bound to both using D3.js v3.  The circle in the code below is assigned a drag behaviour and also a `click` listener.
[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/2EqA3/)

```
var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
    console.log('Start Dragging Group');
})
    .on('drag', function (d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
});

var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
    console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
})
    .on('drag', function (d, i) {
    d.cx += d3.event.dx;
    d.cy += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.cx).attr('cy', d.cy);
});

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 300 300');
var g = svg.selectAll('g').data([{
    x: 10,
    y: 10
}])
    .enter().append('g').call(dragGroup);

g.append('rect').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100);

g.selectAll('circle').data([{
    cx: 90,
    cy: 80
}]).enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
    return d.cx;
})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return d.cy;
})
    .attr('r', 30)
    .call(dragCircle)
    .on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked circle');
});
```

Whenever I click the circle in the example I get the console logging the `drag` event aswell as the `click` event.  I also get the same behavior when dragging, first the `drag` event is logged and on `mouseup` the `click` event gets logged.

What is the correct way to handle these events separately?
The use case is an attempt to handle a node-click and a node-drag/drop in a tree layout.

Comment: Have you tried doing the `preventDefault()` etc also on `dragend`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes I have, also to no avail :(

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075381/d3-mouse-events-click-dragend)?

Comment: Hi Lars,
Many thanks for pointing in the right direction.  It is the solution, perhaps put it in an answer similar to @leMoisela if you like so I can credit you?  Thanks for all your help and attention.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for getting me in the right direction! Was pulling my hair out trying to find out how to capture a drag event in d3

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The key bit that's missing is the check whether the default behaviour of an event has been prevented. That is, there's a matching sibling to `d3.event.preventDefault()` -- `d3.event.defaultPrevented`. You need to check this in your `click` handler to see whether any dragging action is going on.

See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075381/d3-mouse-events-click-dragend).

Comment: Unfortunately d3.event.defaultPrevented does not work consistently. At least in Chrome I have observed that the click handler is still sometimes executed on a drag despite this check.

Comment: @BruceHill It might be worth posting a separate question with the specific problem you're having given that this question is quite old.

Comment: @BruceHill I've noticed the same problem in Chrome on Windows, it doesn't consistently prevent the default.

Comment: I have this issue as well, also observed in Chrome. I believe it has something to do with our draggable nodes, which are complex, comprising multiple path and text elements. I've "fixed" the problem by changing d3: my dragRestore call (line 1235 as of v3.5.8) reads dragRestore(dragged); instead of dragRestore(dragged && d3.event.target === target);

Comment: I commented on https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1005, and the maintainer is in the process of fixing this inconsistency via https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2616

Comment: I am on 3.5.16, which includes github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2616, but I am still seeing this issue with Crome. Firefox is fine.

Comment: @BruceHill i have noticed the same issue in chrome too. Is there any fix?

Comment: @mhd Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 14):

You can differentiate between a `click` and a `dragstart`, but it is harder to differentiate between a `mousdown` and a `dragstart`.

`dragstart` will be triggered when you begin your drag action, meaning when you do your `mousedown`. This is why. whenever you `click`, `dragstart` will be `triggered`. (a `click` is a `mousedown` + `mouseup`).

So **preventing the click to be triggered should work**. In your code, you should add the preventDefault as Lars Kotthoff has hinted. But don't put it in the dragstart function:

```
var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function () {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault(); <-- Remove This
    console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
})
```

And add it on the right place (in the click function), and write it correctly with d3 (d3.event.**defaultPrevented**)

```
g.selectAll('circle').data([{
    cx: 90,
    cy: 80
}]).enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {
    return d.cx
})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return d.cy
})
    .attr('r', 30)
    .call(dragCircle)
    .on('click', click);

function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; <-- Add d3.event.defaultPrevented
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

See [the updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/2EqA3/3/). Now, when dragging, the `click` is not triggered anymore.

Keep in mind that when clicking, the `dragstart` is still triggered. (but not `drag`)

Answer (score 1):

`d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault()` doesn't work as expected or rather its inconsistent.

I faced this issue and to differentiate between the two events, I used a boolean value `isDragged` inside the `onDrag` event. So if this value is set, the `drag` event is performed on the object if not then `click` event is performed.
Also a normal click on object triggers its `dragstart` and `dragend` event but not `onDrag` event.