# d3js preventing drag on click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw a UI in d3js where I have a top panel and I should be able `drag` and `drop` elements to a group and copy them. I have achieved that goal, but there is a bug in  my code. What I actually want to do is, drag the `circle` and copy it. But when I click the `circle` in the top panel it automatically triggers the drag event and copy it self. How can I stop this behaviour?

```
<svg height="600" width="600" style="background: black">

    <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" , width="600" height="40" style="fill:gold;"></rect>
        <circle id='drag' cx="15" cy="20" init-cx="15" init-cy="20" r="10"
                style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:blue"/>

    </g>

    <g id="playground">
        <g>
            <circle id='top' cx="180" cy="120" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle id='top' cx="200" cy="220" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <circle id='top' cx="320" cy="150" r="50" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var move = d3.behavior.drag()
            .on('drag', function () {

                console.log('dragging');

                var curr = d3.select(this)
                    .attr({
                        cx: d3.mouse(this)[0],
                        cy: d3.mouse(this)[1]
                    })


            })
            .on('dragend', function () {

                var curr = d3.select(this);

                d3.select('#playground')
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr({
                        cx : curr.attr('cx'),
                        cy : curr.attr('cy'),
                        r : curr.attr('r')
                    })
                    .style({
                        fill : 'white',
                        stroke : 'red',
                        'stroke-width' : '2px'
                    })
                ;

                curr.attr({
                    cx : curr.attr('init-cx'),
                    cy : curr.attr('init-cx')
                });
            })
            ;


        d3.select('#drag').call(move);


    });


</script>
```

here is the fiddle of my work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/fawzan/my2g724L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will be useful for you,
Have a look.
I've added little code in 'dragend', that is here I'm deciding whether to create/append a circle to playground or not, by using circle's attributes like init-cx and init-cy. The code I've added is

```
var initX = (curr.attr('init-cx')*1);
var currX = (curr.attr('cx')*1);
var initY = (curr.attr('init-cy')*1);
var currY = (curr.attr('cy')*1);                  
if(((currX) > (initX+20)) || ((currY) > (initY+20))){
//Here code to append a circle to playground
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my2g724L/4/)

:D

Comment: Yep, this makes a lot of sense. actually I just had to use the currX, initY point and compare them :D

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the target of drag-end event is the same circle and copy the circle only if they does not match.

```
.on('dragend', function() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.target != this) {
      var curr = d3.select(this);

      d3.select('#playground')
        .append('circle')
        .attr({
          cx: curr.attr('cx'),
          cy: curr.attr('cy'),
          r: curr.attr('r')
        })
        .style({
          fill: 'white',
          stroke: 'red',
          'stroke-width': '2px'
        });

      curr.attr({
        cx: curr.attr('init-cx'),
        cy: curr.attr('init-cx')
      });
    }
});
```

```js
var move = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('drag', function() {

    console.log('dragging');
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this)

    var curr = d3.select(this)
      .attr({
        cx: d3.mouse(this)[0],
        cy: d3.mouse(this)[1]
      })


  })
  .on('dragend', function() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.target != this) {
      var curr = d3.select(this);

      d3.select('#playground')
        .append('circle')
        .attr({
          cx: curr.attr('cx'),
          cy: curr.attr('cy'),
          r: curr.attr('r')
        })
        .style({
          fill: 'white',
          stroke: 'red',
          'stroke-width': '2px'
        });

      curr.attr({
        cx: curr.attr('init-cx'),
        cy: curr.attr('init-cx')
      });
    }
  });


d3.select('#drag').call(move);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="600" width="600" style="background: black">

  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" , width="600" height="40" style="fill:gold;"></rect>
    <circle id='drag' cx="15" cy="20" init-cx="15" init-cy="20" r="10" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:blue" />

  </g>

  <g id="playground">
    <g>
      <circle id='top' cx="180" cy="120" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <circle id='top' cx="200" cy="220" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white" />
    </g>
    <g>
      <circle id='top' cx="320" cy="150" r="50" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Charming as always :D . I think @saikiran's answer suits best.

Comment: Glad you got the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

see your `curr.attr('cx')` offset is returning  15 when clicked.So you can prevent the default action by adding condition on dragend  method:

```
if(curr.attr('cx')==15){
   return false;
}
```

More generic:

```
var isClicked = false;
var move = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', function() {
        isClicked = true;
    })
    .on('drag', function() {
        isClicked = false;

        var curr = d3.select(this)
            .attr({
                cx: d3.mouse(this)[0],
                cy: d3.mouse(this)[1]
            })
    })
    .on('dragend', function() {
        var curr = d3.select(this);
        if (!isClicked) {
            d3.select('#playground')
                .append('circle')
                .attr({
                    cx: curr.attr('cx'),
                    cy: curr.attr('cy'),
                    r: curr.attr('r')
                })
                .style({
                    fill: 'white',
                    stroke: 'red',
                    'stroke-width': '2px'
                });
        }

        curr.attr({
            cx: curr.attr('init-cx'),
            cy: curr.attr('init-cx')
        });
    });


d3.select('#drag').call(move);
d3.select('#drag').on('click', click);
function click(d) {
    isClicked = true;
}
```

check out [Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/my2g724L/2/)

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior?lq=1)

Comment: No offence, but it looks like a lame solution to me. I do not prefer hard coding the coordinates in the program. Because the actual UI is much complicated.

Comment: My bad , you can set a flag and detect `click ` or `drag` event , based on those you can perform action

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean to monitor whether the drag is initiated or not. In this way you can stop dragend function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var isDragged = false;
    var move = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {

            console.log('dragging');
            isDragged = true;
            var curr = d3.select(this)
                .attr({
                    cx: d3.mouse(this)[0],
                    cy: d3.mouse(this)[1]
                })


        })
        .on('dragend', function () {
            if (!isDragged) return;
            isDragged = false;
            var curr = d3.select(this);
            d3.select('#playground')
                .append('circle')
                .attr({
                    cx : curr.attr('cx'),
                    cy : curr.attr('cy'),
                    r : curr.attr('r')
                })
                .style({
                    fill : 'white',
                    stroke : 'red',
                    'stroke-width' : '2px'
                })
            ;

            curr.attr({
                cx : curr.attr('init-cx'),
                cy : curr.attr('init-cx')
            });
        })
        ;


    d3.select('#drag').call(move);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

For D3 v4 (might be applicable to v5 and v6), you can determine the position of the node during the `dragged` event and see if that differs from its original position. Assuming it doesn't, `alphaTarget` is never called.

For example:

```
function dragstarted(d) {
    // if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.2).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    if (d3.event.active && (d.fy != d3.event.y || d.fx != d3.event.x)) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.5).restart();
    }

    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}


function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}
```