# Why aren't the changes to my variable being visible outside of this function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

The following code is a D3 snipped put inside a VueJS instance. The snippet creates circles and lets you drag them.

```
new Vue({
  el: 'body',

  data: {
    x: '',
    y: ''
  },

  computed: {
    pos: function () {
      function click() {

        var point = d3.mouse(this),
          p = { x: point[0], y: point[1] }

        svg.append('circle')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + p.x + ',' + p.y + ')')
          .attr('r', '5')
          .attr('class', 'dot')
          .style('cursor', 'pointer')
          .call(drag)

        var dots = d3.selectAll(".dot")

        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
          .attr('width', 400)
          .attr('height', 400)
          .on('click', click)

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
          .on('drag', dragmove)

        function dragmove(d) {
          var x = d3.event.x
          var y = d3.event.y
          d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
          this.x = x
          console.log('x:', this.x)
      }

    console.log('x:', this.x)
    }
  },

  ready: function () {
  }
})
```

Now, I'm trying to get position x of the dragged circles. The first `console.log('x:', this.x)` logs the position: `x: 190`. But the second long, the one outside of the `dragmove()` function doesn't log anything.

How can I make the second `console.log` log the value of `this.x`?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/unejge3k/1

Comment: do you want the circles translation or just (any) variable x?

Comment: @Fawzan the position of the circles: `x` and `y`. But now I'm only trying to get `x`, to test.

Comment: Are you sure `this` refers to the same object in each case?

Comment: Well you can get the translation `x` , if you want the `x` you need to define it outside the context. I will put an answer.

Comment: @ nnnnnn Oh, you're right. `this.x` inside `dragmove` returns `undefined`. Not the `x` created in `data`. How to address this?

Comment: @alexchenco check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the `x` outside of the `dragmove` function the nyou have to define the `x` in the outer scope.

```
var x, y;

function dragmove(d) {
          x = d3.event.x
          y = d3.event.y
          d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
          this.x = x
          console.log('x:', this.x)
      }
console.log('x:', this.x)
```

But I **really really don't** recommend this method.

Since you want the translation of the circle, you can do it like this.

```
var c = svg.append('circle')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + p.x + ',' + p.y + ')')
          .attr('r', '5')
          .attr('class', 'dot')
          .style('cursor', 'pointer')
          .call(drag)
var trans = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).transalte;

var tx = trans[0];
var ty = trans[1];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Maybe I placed the code in the wrong place? https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/unejge3k/2/

Comment: Yes, it was in the wrong place. Check this snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/unejge3k/3/

Comment: Oh, I see. But now there's no way to append circles.

Comment: If you can tell the exact requirement, May be I can help

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to add circles and drag them around (the behavior of my original fiddle), and then get the position of `x` and `y` of the circle I'm dragging and store them in `this.x` and `this.y` (these last two are defined inside `data : { }`.

Comment: you want to update `this.x` , `this.y` when you drag the circle?

Comment: Yes, that's it, exactly.

Comment: when you say `this.x` do you mean `x` in the `data = { x : '', ..}` ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that this. That's the part of the code belonging to http://vuejs.org/.

Comment: Why don't you put `data.x = x;
                data.y = y;` inside the `dragmove()` function?

Comment: Hey, it worked. Thanks! But a new `svg` tag is created each time I drag a circle. Do you know why? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexcheninfo/unejge3k/6/

Comment: yes, That is because the `click event is triggered when you start the drag.

Comment: You can either use this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior or you can simply check wether an `SVG` exists before you create it. `if(!d3.select('svg').empty()){d3.select('body').append('svg')....}