# d3.js : Differentiate between drag/start/end and click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As the title says, I have an object, and i need all it's drag and click events. There was [some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior) about this issue, but it mainly concerned the click and drag events. (and a reply fiddle didnt work properly)

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dd4nujxo/) here of where I am at. When I drag, click is prevented, but when I click the dragstart and end events fire. I'd like them not to fire when I click, and I'd like click not to fire when I want to drag.

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d){return d})
  .on('drag', function(d){
   d3.select(this).attr('cx', function(d){ return d.x += d3.event.dx });
   d3.select(this).attr('cy', function(d){ return d.y += d3.event.dy });   
   console.log('dragging');
})
.on('dragstart', function(d){
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation()
  console.log('drag start');
})
.on('dragend', function(d){
  console.log('drag end');
})

// ..... 

 MySvgElementWith3DStuffOnIt.on('click', function(){
  if(d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: so many examples online for this. ill have a look for one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works as expected. See updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/dd4nujxo/1/

I have put a few added console logs. When you drag this line :

```
if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) {console.log('return'); return};
```

Will stop the click event from firing. And when you only click, the `dragstart` and `dragend` get fired (as expected), but the `drag` doesn't. Which is why you put the code to move the circle inside the `drag` function. The whole thing works as expected :)

Comment: So i cannot click without triggering the dragstart and dragend at all?

Comment: I don't think so, what would be the problem with this ?

Comment: Iam writing a collaborative graph app, and when you click on the node it would add a new node, and when you drag it would lock it from others, also a grid would show up when you start dragging. And it looks annoying when I click on the node and the grid flashes up. Yeah it's nothing earth shattering, but it's still.

Comment: just place this code in the drag rather than drag start ?

Comment: That'll have to do. Won't be the most fancyfull solution, but it'll work.

Comment: That's all that matters ;) Won't be noticeable. But i think its the only solution. If you think about it what is classed by drag start ? Technically it's just a click right as once you start to move it, that changes to drag ? And drag end ? That'l be letting go of the click too ? So it all works as expected :)

Comment: When I run this example and click on the circle, I still get all three drag events: drag start, dragging, and drag end. Running Chrome 64

Comment: @val Did you get any solution for the first comment you made in this question?

Answer (score 3):

A small update of @thatOneGuy to use d3v4 drag module

https://jsfiddle.net/mhebrard/q5eL5qyv/

```
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on('drag', function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', function(d){ return d.x += d3.event.dx });
    d3.select(this).attr('cy', function(d){ return d.y += d3.event.dy });   
    console.log('dragging');
  })
  .on('start', function(d){
    console.log('drag start');
  })
  .on('end', function(d){
    console.log('drag end');
  })
```

Comment: When I run this example and click on the circle, I still get all three drag events: drag start, dragging, and drag end. Running Chrome 64