# Click event causing drag event as well in force layout graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is an excerpt of my JS code to implement a force layout graph in D3. I have two requirements:

1. **Clicking** a node should cause child nodes to be retrieved from the backend and added to the graph (this works).
2. When **dragging** a node, it should remain fixed when dragging stops. When that same node is clicked in combination with the <kbd>CMD</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, the node should be released again. (this works as well)

My issue is that **when I click a node to expand it further, the node becomes fixed as well**. Thus, clicking inadvertently caused the drag event to be called. Dragging however does not cause the node to expand further (due to `if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;`).

```js
function visNetwork(graph_id) {

    this.graph_id = graph_id;

    /* Some code removed for brevity */

    var dragstart = function(d) {
        console.log('Detected drag...');
        d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
    };

    // set up the D3 visualisation in the specified element
    var w = 2000,
        h = 2000;

    var vis = d3.select("#svg-container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", this.graph_id)
        //necessary to convert the SVG to canvas
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
         //better to keep the viewBox dimensions with variables
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h )
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-1500)
        .linkDistance(150)
        .size([w, h])
        .gravity(.1);

    var drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);

    var nodes = force.nodes(),
        links = force.links();

    var update = function() {
        var link = vis.selectAll("line")
            .data(links, function(d) {
                return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
            });

        link.enter().insert("line", "g")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id;
            })
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke", "#ccc");

        link.exit().remove();

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) {
                return d.id;
            });

        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .on('click', function(d, i) {
                if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
                    console.log('Ignoring click event...');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Captured click event...');

                //Release fixed node when CTRL or CMD key is pressed
                if (d3.event.ctrlKey || d3.event.metaKey) {
                    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
                    return;
                }
                modifyGraph(d.id, d3.event);
                })
                .call(drag);

        nodeEnter.append("svg:circle"); /* Code removed for brevity */

        nodeEnter.append("svg:text"); /* Code removed for brevity */

        node.exit().remove();

        force.on("tick", function() { /* Code removed for brevity */ });
        // Restart the force layout.
        force.start();
    };
    update();
}
```

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? Read also the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951105/1006854).

Comment: could you mock up a fiddle that shows the basics of your problem ?

Comment: @mef I'm using D3.js version 3.5.12

Comment: Would it be possible to fix the node once "drag" occurs, and ignore "dragstart"?

Comment: @Culme yes, that actually fixed it. I replaced `dragstart` by `drag`. This is also hinted at when looking at [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior/19951105#19951105) @mef referenced and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19077477/3165737): `click` will still call `dragstart`, but it won't call `drag` because of the `d3.event.defaultPrevented` check.

Comment: @Culme if you'd create an answer out of your comment, I'd happily accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could achieve what you want by fixing the node once "drag" occurs, ignoring "dragstart" altoghether.

Please also read the [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931307/d3-differentiate-between-click-and-drag-for-an-element-which-has-a-drag-behavior/19951105#19951105) linked to by @mef in the comments section, which contains more on the subject.